# PHP Filename cannot be empty how to bypass that in simple html dom line 70

Tags: php, scrape

As i was scraping one site and i was able to make it to 4000 out of 10000 contents it would stop and say

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   /Users...simple_html_dom.php on line 70 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a
>   member function find() on a non-object

in line 70 of simple_html_dom.php

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
```

I would like to know how to bypass the empty filename and move on to continue to complete the process?

Comment: Please post more code.  Especially the code that defines your variables.

Comment: Why not just add a check for `$url` being an empty string?

Comment: What was the value of `$url` when the error occured?

Comment: it is empty but just wanted to know how to bypass it and continue from there without filling in the blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$contents = '';
if(!empty($url)) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
}
```

Comment: will it fill that row blank if value is empty? i would like to bypass and not fill in the blank and continue

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to ensure that $url has a value...

```
if(!empty($url)) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
}
```

Comment: will it fill that row blank if value is empty? i would like to bypass and not fill in the blank and continue

Comment: @merrill, you have only given us one line of code to work with and there is no way that we can answer that question. You'll have to post more code or look at the rest of the code yourself. Most likely, you'll have to move more code inside of that IF block.